# Satchmo Delayed Payment

Tags: django, payment-processing, satchmo

Is there any way that Satchmo can be setup to authorize payments on checkout but not to capture the funds until instructed? The docs speak of the payment backends supporting authorize_payment and capture_payment but i can't find the setting to activate this behavior. Has anyone done this before/know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/satchmo-developers/browse_thread/thread/4d25ed0f308db701) on satchmo mailing list suggests that payment is authorized first and captured when order is marked as shipped.  Note that not all payment gateways support authorization -- check `can_authorize` and `can_capture` methods of `PaymentProcessor` in a module corresponding to gateway you're going to use.